# How can I get unique data inside the antd modal component when I have multiple modals on the page?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've got a really weird situation. On my site's home page I have three of the same Components. The component holds a button that triggers a modal. For each of the components, the content inside the modal will be specific to a company id and logo. I pass in the information via properties. I can see the content of the button be specific to the company, but inside the modal? It is all three of the modals has the same content as the very last component in the list. I'm not sure why that is happening?

I've tried setting an id on the modal that matches the company id but that didn't make a difference.

I even tried consoling out the the variables i'm passing in, printing them out inside the component, and see that the components are getting the correct variables, but those same variables inside the modal are all set to the last component's values.

For additional context, there's three companies in the array. I'm doing this thing where I show them in three columns in a row. I have the first company in the middle and the second and third ones being on either side of it.

The component that contains the modal code is placed on the page like this:

```
<ReviewNew key={1} rankPlacementId={'2'} companyId={companyList[1].id} seoName={companyList[1].seo_name} companyLogo={companyList[1].logo_svg} />
```

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from '../Shared/NavBar';
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
import useToken from '../useToken';
import reqwest from "reqwest";
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Col, Layout, Row, Button, Form, Input, Modal, Rate, notification, Image, Divider, Alert, Space } from 'antd';
import LoadingSpinner from './../Shared/LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner';
import reviewNewStyles from './ReviewNew.module.css';
import { reviewStore } from '../../context/Store';

const { Header, Content } = Layout;
const { TextArea } = Input;

export default function ReviewNew({ rankPlacementId, companyId, seoName, companyLogo }) {
    console.log('ReviewNew', rankPlacementId, companyId, seoName);
    let history = useHistory();
    const [company, setCompany] = useState({});
    const [componentDisabled, setComponentDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [review, setReview] = useState({});
    const [showNotLoggedIn, setShowNotLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const { token, setToken } = useToken();
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const [modalRankPlacementId, setModalRankPlacementId] = useState(rankPlacementId);
    const [modalCompanyId, setModalCompanyId] = useState(companyId);
    const [modalSeoName, setModalSeoName] = useState(seoName);
    const [modalCompanyLogo, setModalCompanyLogo] = useState(companyLogo);

    const layout = {
        wrapperCol: {
            span: 16,
        },
    };
    const tailLayout = {
        wrapperCol: {
            span: 20,
        },
    };


    const visible = reviewStore(state => state.toggled);
    const showReview = reviewStore(state => state.toggle);


    // Verify if user is logged in, hide modal and display error notification.
    const checkLogin = () => {
        console.log(token);
        if (!token || token.access_token === null) {
            console.log('not logged in');
            showReview();
            setComponentDisabled(true);
            notification.error({
                message: 'Error',
                description: 'Please login to continue!'
            });
            return false
        } else {
            console.log('logged in');
            setComponentDisabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }
    const createReview = async (params = {}) => {
        params = { company_id: modalCompanyId, ...params };
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await reqwest({
                url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/companies/${modalSeoName}/reviews`,
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "access-token": token.access_token,
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "client": token.client,
                    "uid": token.uid
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'review': params }),
                type: 'json'
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            notification.success({
                message: 'Success',
                description: 'Review created successfully!'
            });
            showReview
            history.push(`/car-warranty-reviews/${seoName}`);
        } catch (error) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setReview(JSON.parse(error.response).review);
            notification.error({
                message: 'Error',
                description: JSON.parse(error.response).review.error_message
            });
            showReview
        }
    }

    const customFetch = async (params = {}) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        if (!token || token.access_token === null) {
            setComponentDisabled(true);
            setShowNotLoggedIn(true);
        }
        // const response = await reqwest({
        //     url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/companies/${seoName}`,
        //     method: "get",
        //     headers: {
        //         "Accept": "application/json",
        //         "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        //     },
        //     type: "json"
        // });

        // setCompany(response.company)

        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        customFetch({});
    }, []);

    const onFinish = (values) => {
        checkLogin() && createReview(values);
    };

    const onFinishFailed = (values) => {
        notification.error({
            message: 'Error',
            description: 'Something went wrong'
        });
    };

    return (
        <div id={companyId}>
            <Button onClick={() => showReview()} className={reviewNewStyles.compareButton} >Write a Review {companyId} {modalSeoName}</Button>
            <Modal
                id={companyId}
                open={visible}
                centered
                className='flex justify-center items-center'
                disabled={componentDisabled}
                closable={false}
                destroyOnClose={true}
                footer={[
                    <Button key="back" onClick={() => showReview()}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                ]}
            >
                <Header className={reviewNewStyles.header}>
                    <Row justify="center" align="middle">
                        <Col>
                            <Image preview={false} src={modalCompanyLogo} alt="company logo" />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Header>
                <Content align="center" className={reviewNewStyles.contentWrapper}>
                    <span id='review-form-wrapper'>
                        <Row id='review-form' className=''>
                            <Col span={24} className='flex justify-center items-center'>
                                <Form
                                    {...layout}
                                    colon={false}
                                    labelAlign="right"
                                    form={form}
                                    labelCol={{
                                        span: 4,
                                    }}
                                    wrapperCol={{
                                        span: 16,
                                    }}
                                    onFinish={onFinish}
                                    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
                                    requiredMark="true"
                                    initialValues={review}
                                >
                                    <Row className='flex'>
                                        <Col span={24}>
                                            <h4 className='text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-0'>Write A Review {modalCompanyId}  {modalSeoName}</h4>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                    <div className='flex flex-col items-left justify-items-center'>
                                        <Form.Item>
                                            <Form.Item
                                                name="rating"
                                                required
                                                hasFeedback
                                                rules={[
                                                    {
                                                        required: true,
                                                        message: 'Please choose a rating!',
                                                    },
                                                ]}
                                            >
                                                <Rate allowHalf style={{ color: '#EE9924', fontSize: 25 }} />

                                            </Form.Item>
                                            <label>Rating</label>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                        <Form.Item>
                                            <Form.Item
                                                name="content"
                                                required
                                                hasFeedback
                                                rules={[
                                                    {
                                                        required: true,
                                                        message: 'Please write a review!',
                                                    }
                                                ]}
                                            >
                                                <TextArea
                                                    rows={4}
                                                />
                                            </Form.Item>
                                            <label>Write your Review</label>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                        {(showNotLoggedIn && <Row justify="center" align="middle">
                                            <Col span={24}>
                                                <Space direction="vertical" size="large">
                                                    <Alert message="Please login to continue!" type="error" showIcon />
                                                </Space>
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>)}
                                        <Row className='flex item-center justify-center'>
                                            <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                                                <Button
                                                    type="primary"
                                                    htmlType="submit"
                                                    className={reviewNewStyles.compareButton}
                                                >
                                                    Submit
                                                </Button>
                                            </Form.Item>
                                        </Row>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </span>

                </Content>
            </Modal >
        </div>
    )
}
```